# Не работает вывод json

Tags: jquery, json

Написал скрипт, который парсит json-строку, добавляет ссылку и картинку перед ссылкой, но в вывод ничего не попадает. Где ошибка?

```
$(function(){
    $.getJSON('/json/airports.json', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, field) {
            var airport_name = field['name_translations']['ru'] ? 'ru' : 'en';
            $('<a>')
            .attr({'id': i, 'class': 'airport-link'})
            .text(field['name_translations'][airport_name])
            .parent().prepend('<img>')
            .attr({'src': '/img/flags/' + field['country_code'].toLowerCase() + '.png', 'data-sorter': field['country_code'].toLowerCase()})
            .appendTo('#airport-list');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `parent()` - откуда возьмется `parent` у элемента, который еще никуда не вставлен?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Можно было сделать гораздо проще. Внести все данные в переменную, а в конце append эту переменную к нужному блоку:

```
$(function(){
        $.getJSON('/json/airports.json', function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(i, field) {
                var airport_name = field['name_translations']['ru'] ? 'ru' : 'en';
                var airport = '<div class="single-airport"><img src="/img/flags/' + field['country_code'].toLowerCase() + '.png" /><a id="' + i + '" class="airport-link">' + field['name_translations'][airport_name] + '</a></div>';
                $('#airport-list').append(airport);
            });
        });
    });
```